# How to extract tuple type from array?

Tags: typescript

```
function makeTupleByArgs<T extends Array<any>>(...items: T) {
    return items;
}
function makeTupleByArray<T extends Array<any>>(items: T) {
    return items;
}

const a = makeTupleByArgs(1, 3, "ABC");       // [number, number, string]
const b = makeTupleByArray([1, 3, "ABC"]);    // (string | number)[]
```

`makeTupleByArgs` returns tuple type, but `makeTupleByArray` returns normal array.

How can I make tuple from array or extract tuple type from array? And what is difference between two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler uses heuristics to determine the most suitable type to infer for a value.  Generally, array literals will be inferred as [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) and not [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), unless there is some special context in which the compiler thinks tuples are desired.

So just writing

```
const array = [1, 3, "ABC"]; 
// const array: (string | number)[]
```

will result in an array type.  And once that has happened, it's too late to get the tuple back from it, because that specific order and length information has been lost.  So no matter how you declare `makeTupleByArray()`, the following will always fail to give you a tuple type:

```
// it's too late now because array is not a tuple type
makeTupleByArray(array); // (string | number)[]
```

So the only possible way to get a tuple type is to *either* explicitly tell the compiler so (such as with a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) or a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const explicitlyAnnotatedTuple: [number, number, string] = [1, 3, "ABC"];
// const explicitlyAnnotatedTuple: [number, number, string]

const constAssertedTuple = [1, 3, "ABC"] as const;
// const constAssertedTuple: readonly [1, 3, "ABC"]
```

*or* to pass an array literal directly into a specially-defined `makeTupleByArray()` which hints that you want a tuple for `items` if possible.  Such hints are traditionally a little weird, and it would be nice if you could get something like a `const` assertion in the call signature (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a relevant feature request)...

...**but since [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) were introduced in TypeScript 4.0, you can use `[...T]` instead of `T` to give such a hint:**

```
function makeTupleByArray<T extends Array<any>>(items: [...T]) {
  return items;
}

const b = makeTupleByArray([1, 3, "ABC"]); // [number, number, string]
```

Again, here we've defined `makeTupleByArray` to take an `items` of type `[...T]`, which tells the compiler that when it looks at `[1, 3, "ABC"]` it should prefer to interpret it as being of a tuple type instead of just an array type, and so `T` is inferred as `[number, number, string]` instead of `(number | string)[]`.  Hooray!

And this is great, but remember that no matter how you define `makeTupleByArray`, you will never recover the tuple type after it has been discarded:

makeTupleByArray(array); // still (string | number)[] even with our fancy signature

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAVEAHAG0wCEBPAQQCdLVSAebRTADykzABMBnRKm+1GFIA+YQAoYbZFwBciANoA6ZdgC6ASkQBvAFCJElTFBCUkkzNIDcOgL46dEBFyiJU1WogC8CgIwAaRABmAIAicmIAYRDVawB6WMRHMGdXd1I5MWdKGDAAc0QAH0QwEGQAI0xKdXlVezQsXEISCjSxN351S0R4xEyobLzC4tKKqpr7JJSWQhgISQIKMDA4KFQ2DkaiOXkS8sqA3dGArJzc1S9fAODEMMjouITJl2mCWfnF5dX1zcxtw-3hntKMd+qdag4nC4nuQuFxKt98EQLvJ-EFQuEoudUDwng9EpD8ckoDC4ZQEU05IZUBwEAtLmibhjovYJgSyhd6jhEc0+LQxCirui7houvpugkdiMAf9gYgTnlakA)

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this `items: [...T]`

Answer (score 1):

When `T` is inferred, it will usually be inferred as the most specific type to fit the actual arguments, albeit often with literals like `1` or `"ABC"` widened to `number` or `string`. Hence, in your first test case, `T` is inferred as `[number, number, string]` because that's the most specific thing `T` can be.

So likewise, `T` is `(string | number)[]` in the second test case. This is the most specific thing `T` can be, because the argument itself has that type. The expression `[1, 3, "ABC"]` will, in most contexts, be given the type `(string | number)[]`, for example:

```
let test = [1, 3, "ABC"];
// test: (string | number)[]
```

This is wider than `[number, number, string]` because the Typescript language designers presumably didn't want to assume that you wanted the array to always be two numbers then a string. The type `(string | number)[]` is more generally useful in code which uses arrays, because array methods like `push` or `pop` will preserve that array type but would not preserve the tuple type.

On the occasions where you want to write `[1, 3, "ABC"]` and have it be a tuple, you can write `[1, 3, "ABC"] as const`. In this case it will be given the tuple type `readonly [1, 3, "ABC"]`. So you could write your function like below:

```
function makeTupleByArray<T extends readonly any[]>(items: T) {
    return items;
}

const b = makeTupleByArray([1, 3, "ABC"] as const);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAVEAHAG0wCEBPAQQCdLVSAebRTADykzABMBnRSzVDggKlEqMKQDaAXQB8AChhtkXAFyJsASkQBvAFCIDvTFBCUkizMoDcugL67dEBFyiIARogC8KDDnxEyKhpSOQkARgAaRABmKIAicmIAYTipUR4nMBcNGyA)